# How can i get autonumber custome like GU0001

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hi I need to make my Order code to be like `GU0001`, the number is coming from the increment id

I have tried

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="order_code" value="GU000{{ $sup[0]->id+1 }}">
```

When I tried this with empty data in $sup, its show error 'undifined offset:0, But when there is a data, there is no error

Comment: `GU000{{ ((empty($sup)? 0: $sup[0]->id) + 1) }}`

Answer (score 1):

Check below code

```
<?php
$prefix = "GU"; //code should be whatever you want
$num_length = 5; //decide this number first
$auto_increment_id = 1; //this is dynamic value
$unique_value = $prefix.str_pad($auto_increment_id,$num_length,"0");

//result : GU00001
?>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="order_code" value="{{ $unique_value }}">
```

Comment: can you tell me how to get the increment id from the database to replace ```1``` in $auto_increment_id

Comment: First insert current record into database and get last insert id. this will be your unique auto incremented id and then update $unique_value for current record into database.

Comment: can you give me example if the $sup->id is empty ?

Comment: i have tried using this `@if (!empty($gudang))<input class="form-control" type="text" name="kode_gudang" value="GU001" readonly> @endif <input class="form-control" type="text" name="kode_gudang" value="{{ $unique_value }}" readonly>` but it error again 'undefined offset'

Comment: First insert row and get last inserted id then set into $auto_increment_id. After that prepare $unique_value and then update $unique value into last inserted id row. let me know if any confusion.

Comment: First insert row then update last inserted row based on last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is related to undefined offset then you should use ternary operator to solve this.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="order_code" value="GU000{{ (!empty($sup)?$sup[0]->id+1:"") }}">
```

Comment: Hi it solve the undefined offset but i still can't get the increment id+1

Comment: Do you mean that this $sup[0]->id+1 always return same result?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I made typo error here !empty($sup)